# Command line switch to start chromium under a profile

Tags: linux, browser, chromium

I have two users created in Chromium, user A and user B. Is there a command line option to start Chromium with the user you want?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use the [`--user-data-dir`](http://www.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory) switch.